# Knife bootstrap does nothing

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

When the command is run to bootstrap a node using Knife, it just says bootstrapping and then does nothing

```
sudo knife bootstrap 10.0.0.2 -x root -P pssword -N cheffirstnode
```

And the output is -- Bootstrapping Chef on 10.0.0.2

And then the execution of the command stops. What could be the reason as I can ping from the Workstation to Chefserver and vice-versa.
I can also ping from the node to the Chef Server but the Chef Server cannot contact the node. Could this be the reason ? I am not sure as it is not giving any error ? Is there any way to see the logs of this command as it can help to pin-point the problem.

Comment: Bootstrapping can take a long time. Especially when I had a remote Chef administrator station, I had to pipe the output to a file so my SSL session wouldn't time out waiting for the admin station to report back results. When you say 'execution stops,' do you mean you're returned to the command prompt? How long have you waited? Have you SSL'ed onto the target box to peek at what it's doing?

Comment: You have not specified a run list for the node. See the "-r" parameter of the bootstrap command.

Answer (score 1):

Login to the node and check the hostname. See if you are able to bootstrap with the hostname. I was facing this issue too. For some reason the IP you use is not detected by the workstation especially when you are on vagrant. Hostname can be obtained by running 'hostname' command on the node. Also another alternative that worked for me was bootstrapping using SSH.

> knife bootstrap hostname --ssh-user username --ssh-password password --ssh-port 2222 --run-list "recipe[IfAny]" --sudo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom, in my case it was just the password being incorrect (copy/paste messed up).

I would've expected an authentication error rather than just:

```
Connecting to <hostname>
```